# Style text input placeholder

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change an input’s HTML5 placeholder color with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css)

Is there anyway to style the color of a placeholder in a text input? Right now I'm stuck with the boring default grey.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You sure can http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/style-placeholder-text/.

(from the above article)

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: red;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
    color: red;  
}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
    color: red;  
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   color: red;  
}
```

Or check MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:-moz-placeholder

Comment: Hey, would it be possible to group those selectors in a single line?