# Change input placeholder color darker

Tags: css, input, textarea, placeholder

Follow this article ([Style text input placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14617200/style-text-input-placeholder)), i can change the color of the text input placeholder to red color. But it is always a light-red color, not red exactly.

Is there any way to make it a red color exactly?

**update**

The color on Chrome is red (this is correct), the color on Firefox is not red, it is light-red  or blurred, i guessed that.

[image: http://i279.photobucket.com/albums/kk132/svincoll4/2013-03-19_181239_zps84166305.png]

---

EDIT (from the OP answer):

Please check this example (http://jsfiddle.net/LQkQG/), the color is red on Chrome, but `light-red` on Firefox.
I want the color on Firefox same with the Chrome.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I've found you need to override opacity.

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
    color:    red;
     opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

Comment: gnarly, i didn't notice Chrome hanging on to the opacity!

Comment: now your only change the color for webkit browsers

::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
    color:    #999;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
    color:    #999;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
    color:    #999;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
    color:    #999;
}

Comment: This answer should set the opacity in `::-moz-placeholder {}` since *Firefox* is the browser with the lower opacity.

Answer (score 22):

Yes, by setting its value through HEX (hexadecimal) you get better control of what color to use.
The color for bright red (as red as it gets) is `#FF0000`

Firefox, however is a rebel needs to be told what opacity to use.

For reference take a look at [this chart](http://html-color-codes.com/)

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #FF0000;
    opacity: 1 !important; /* for older chrome versions. may no longer apply. */
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
    color: #FF0000;
    opacity: 1 !important;
}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
    color: #FF0000;
    opacity: 1 !important;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   color: #FF0000;
}
```

Comment: This answer should set the opacity in `::-moz-placeholder {}` since *Firefox* is the browser with the lower opacity.

Answer (score -3):

Input a hexidecimal value for the color.

Maybe use a tool like http://www.colorpicker.com/ ?

Answer (score -4):

visit: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_colors.asp

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

    input, textarea { color: #000; }
    .placeholder { color: #aaa; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">

            <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="enter a text" />
            <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="test()" />
</form>
```

in the place of color code you can write which ever color you want

Comment: CSS class selectors have nothing to do with HTML attributes :)