# I want to show opacity:1 for input[type="number"] placeholders

Tags: html, css, gecko

I have one form having `input[type="number"]`.

Placeholder shows reduced opacity on browsers.
I want to show `opacity:1` for input placeholders.
It is showing correct for `input[type="text"]` but not for  `input[type="number"]`.

Not getting why is it so.

**CSS**:

```
input::-moz-placeholder{
  opacity: 1
}

textarea::-moz-placeholder{
  opacity: 1
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you please add your code on fiddle?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change input placeholder color darker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15497550/change-input-placeholder-color-darker)

Answer (score 1):

Try marking the css as important so that would be rendered

```
input::moz-placeholder
{
   opacity:1 !important
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in firefox. Which seems not working in firefox.

Check [Firefox bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1119693) And [Firefox bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1004130)

Comment: Sorry for late reply but ya its a bug in firefox so any other experiment ?

Answer (score 0):

try this with extended support

```
input[type="number"]::moz-placeholder { 
  opacity:1 !important;
}
input[type="number"]:moz-placeholder { 
  opacity:1 !important;
}
input[type="number"]::-webkit-input-placeholder { 
  opacity:1 !important;
}

input[type="number"]:-ms-input-placeholder { 
  opacity:1 !important;
}
```